# Counter object as a class data member

Tags: c++

I am reading Counting Objects in C++ from Scott Meyers: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/counting-objects-in-c/184403484.
He defines a `Counter` class:

```
class Counter {  
public:          
    Counter() { ++count; }
    Counter(const Counter&) { ++count; }
    ~Counter() { --count; }
    static size_t howMany()
        { return count; }

private:
    static size_t count;
};
// This still goes in an
// implementation file
size_t Counter::count = 0;
```

The article says that one way to use this class is as a class data member:

```
class Widget {
public:
    .....  // all the usual public
           // Widget stuff
    static size_t howMany()
    { return Counter::howMany(); }
private:
    .....  // all the usual private
           // Widget stuff
    Counter c;
};
```

My question is related to the expression `Counter c;`. If we are using a static method of `Counter`, why is a `Counter` object inside `Widget` declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there in order to increment the counter when a new instance of `Widget` is created.

When a `Counter` is a member of `Widget`, the constructor of `Counter` gets invoked whenever a `Widget` is created. This in turn, increments the value of the `count` variable of the `Counter`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `Counter` object works is that it does its job in its constructors and destructors. If you want `Widget` to use `Counter` for counting, you need to make sure that `Widget`'s constructors call `Counter`'s constructors, and also that `Widget`'s destructor calls `Counter`'s destructor.

You can achieve this by making `Counter` an instance member of `Widget`. Even though `Widget` never accesses `Counter`'s methods explicitly, C++ makes sure of calling `Counter`'s constructor and destructor implicitly, as long as `Counter` is a data member of the `Widget` class. Note that making `Counter` a `static` member of `Widget` would not have achieved the same goal, because constructor and destructor calls on the instance of `Widget` are not routed to its `static` data members.

Answer (score 1):

The real solution is a bit down the line in the article. The code you posted only serves the end goal as a means of illustration. That is not the real solution.

The real solution is to make `Counter` a class template.

```
template <typename T>
class Counter {
public:
    Counter() { ++count; }
    Counter(const Counter&) { ++count; }
    ~Counter() { --count; }

    static size_t howMany()
    { return count; }

private:
    static size_t count;
};

template <typename T>
size_t Counter<T>::count = 0;
```

And then, use it as a parent class of classes for which you want to count the objects.

```
// inherit from Counter to count objects
class Widget: public Counter<Widget> {    
    .....
};
```

**I am adding this as an extension.**  This does not appear in the article you linked to.

```
// inherit from Counter to count objects
class Foo: public Counter<Foo> {    
    .....
};
```

Now, both `Widget` and `Foo` have the functionality.